# Get std::thread's thread:id before it runs?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

I'm trying to build a thread-safety layer on top of C++ 11's `std::thread` where each object is assigned to an owning thread, and certain calls can raise a hard error when they are used on the wrong thread. The owning thread is the only one that can transfer an object to another thread.

I have it all working, *except* that I can't find a way to get a thread's `thread::id` before it is actually running. And I need to attach the new thread's ID to the object before I hand it off.

If I use

```
std::thread newThread( [theObject]()
                       {
                           // use theObject here.
                       } );
```

The earliest point I can get the thread's ID is after the definition of the thread object, at which point the thread is already running.

I see there is a default constructor for `std::thread`, but I can't see a way to give it a function to run on the thread afterwards.

Is there a way to perform two-step construction on a thread, or control the thread's ID at time of creation?

Comment: Writing the thread function so it immediately blocks, to be released by the main thread when the constructor completes and the id is known, is pretty common.

Comment: Could you store the *address* of the thread rather than the `id`? Then, if you still need the `id`. you can always obtain it from the *address* (`thread->get_id()`).

Comment: @Galik That's the same problem just in a different shape. I can't get the address until after the constructor has returned, at which point the thread is already running and might have already encountered code that needs to know the thread ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start each thread inactived by passing a unique std::promise parameter, get the thread id first ( thread id is used as a pass by reference parameter for the purpose) afterwards let it wait for the promise to be set by the thread manager. This will also remove the hassle of using a conditional variable.

**Edited** Snippet

```
class smart_thread {
public:
    smart_thread(std::function<void(void)> task)
    {
        thread_ = std::thread([=]() {
            id_ = std::this_thread::get_id();
            // wait here till activated
            future_.get();
            if(active_) task();
        });
    }

    void activate()  {
        promise_.set_value();
        active_ = true;
    }

    ~smart_thread() {
        if(!active_) promise_.set_value();
        thread_.join();
    }    
private:
    std::thread::id id_;
    std::atomic<bool> active_ = false;
    std::thread thread_;
    std::promise<void> promise_;
    std::future<void> future_ = promise_.get_future();
};

void main()
{
    auto task = []() { std::cout << "Hello World\n"; };
    smart_thread thread(task); // start thread inactive mode
    thread.activate(); // activate thread
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Rather than getting the ID of the thread before it starts running, you could consider having the function the thread executes do some initial setup before taking off. For example, you could do something like this:

```
bool isReady = false;
bool wasReceived = false;
std::mutex mutex;
std::condition_variable condition;

std::thread newThread([theObject, &isReady, &mutex, &condition] {
   /* Wait until we've been cleared to go. */
   std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(isReady);
   condition.wait(lock, [&isReady] { return isReady; });

   /* Signal that we're done. */
   wasReceived = true;
   lock.unlock();
   condition.notify_one();

   /* Put code here to do whatever it is that the thread should do. */
});

/* Read the thread's ID. It's currently waiting for us. */
auto id = newThread.get_id();

/* Tell the thread that we're ready for it. */
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
isReady = true;
condition.notify_one();

/* Wait until the thread has confirmed that it's ready. */
condition.wait(lock, [&] { return wasReceived; });
```

This creates the thread and has it sit and wait until the creator has a chance to read its ID. Once that's happened, the creator then waits until the thread confirms that it's ready to go, and from there you can work with the thread ID however you'd like.

Beware of bugs in the above code - it's completely untested. :-)

Comment: Thank you, that is a good approach, and even better explanation.

Answer (score 5):

No--as soon as you create a thread, it starts to run. If you want to get its ID before it does (much of) anything, you probably want to create a little wrapper, where you pass the thread (for example) a CV and a queue where it deposits its output.

Then when the thread starts up, it retrieves its own ID, deposits it in the output queue, and then waits on the CV. When the parent has retrieved the ID, and is ready for the child to start doing something, it signals the CV, and off it goes.

Comment: What is a `CV`? Even removing "curriculum vitae" from the web search results, I don't find any expansion for that that I can fit into this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to create a template class that accepts the thread routine in the form of a `std::function<void(T *object)>`.  This can easily be done with an anonymous closure if additional parameters need to be passed in.

```
template <class T>
class ThreadWrapper
{
public:
    ThreadWrapper(std::function<void(T *object)> function, T *object) :
    {
        m_thread = std::thread(WrapFunction, function, object);
        //optionally
        m_thread.detach();
    }
    static void WrapFunction(ThreadWrapper *wrapper, std::function<void()> function, T *object)
    {
        // Get the thread id and save in the object
        object->SetThreadId(get_id());
        // Now actually invoke the thread routine, with the id already installed.
        function(object);
    }
}

// Cleanup is left as an exercise for the reader.
```

Beware of bugs in the above code - it's completely untested. :-) :-)

Comment: This doesn't work in my case. I want the source thread to be the only one permitted to modify an object's owning thread. `WrapFunction` already runs on the new thread, so a race condition could occur where the source thread gives the same object to two threads, and then it would be random which of them got it. If only the owning thread may transfer ownership, after transferring the object the first time, doing it a second time would immediately produce an error, in the spot where the second transfer happens, and not when the first thread tries to use the object after the transfer has happened.

Comment: @uliwitness I understand.  Yes that is an issue with this, I hadn't considered the case of the current owning thread trying to pass its owned object off twice in rapid succession.  I was viewing this from a "single ownership" perspective where the thread that's releasing the object should consider that it no longer owns the object as soon as the construction of the `ThreadWrapper` has completed.  Somewhat akin to assigning a `unique_ptr<>` to another owner. ...

Comment: @uliwitness ... A possible solution would be to duplicate the code that uses `SetThreadId` on the object in the `ThreadWrapper` ctor, immediately after creating the thread.  The `ThreadWrapper` ctor would also need to check ownership of the object before doing anything, and throw an exception if it doesn't own it.  That said, you still need both calls to `SetThreadId`.  One to avoid race conditions in the releasing thread, the other to avoid race conditions in the acquiring thread.  Tis also raises the question of how should the failure be detected in the case of an attempted double handoff?

Comment: I'm using a `std::atomic::compare_exchange_strong()`, so if the sender passes in its own thread ID as the expected current value and the destination thread as the new value, it will automatically tell me if we're no longer the owner in the spot where the second assign attempt happens.